# Error en Ionic 2: "No component factory found for"

Tags: typescript, ionic2, excepciones, angular

Estoy tratando de mostrar una nueva pagina en una *app* de **ionic** (la *app* no fue creada por mi, solo me han encargado modificarla), cuando ejecuto `this.navCtrl.push(aportacionesPage)` me devuelve el siguiente error:

> No component factory found for AportacionesPage

Intentare ser algo mas especifico con mi código aunque como no manejo mucho *ionic* no se si sobrara o faltara.

En los imports ya tengo introducida la pagina a la que quiero ir

```
import { AportacionesPage } from '../aportaciones/aportaciones';
```

La pagina a la que quiero ir esta bien construida y no presenta errores de compilacion, la clase esta con el contenido de otra pagina de la app que funciona bien (he probado tambien a hacer el `push` a esa otra pagina y funciona). Lo unico que tiene cambiado de su copia son los nombres.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-aportaciones',
  templateUrl: 'aportaciones.html'
})
export class AportacionesPage {
....
}
```

La sentencia `push` se ejecuta en un evento `click`

```
<div class="btn_aportaciones">
    <button (click)='irAportaciones()'>{{ 'foro-hilo.mis_aportaciones' | translate }}</button>    
  </div>
```

Y el método es el siguiente:

```
irAportaciones(item) {     
    console.log("PRUEBA DEL LOG FUNCIONANDO");     
    this.navCtrl.push(aportaciones, {
      //view: 'order'
    }).then(
      response => {
        console.log('Response ' + response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }
    ).catch(exception => {
      console.log('Exception ' + exception);
    });      
  }
```

Al pulsar sobre el boton me muestra estos errores:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./ForoHiloPage class ForoHiloPage - inline template:76:4 caused by: No component factory found for AportacionesPage
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:52944
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:110388
>   next @ main.js:35926
>   schedulerFn @ main.js:37436
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.js:12385
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ main.js:12334
>   Subscriber._next @ main.js:12287
>   Subscriber.next @ main.js:12251
>   Subject.next @ main.js:14484
>   EventEmitter.emit @ main.js:37428
>   NgZone.triggerError @ main.js:38278
>   onHandleError @ main.js:38257
>   t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   invoke @ polyfills.js:3

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No component factory found for AportacionesPage
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:52946
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:110388
>   next @ main.js:35926
>   schedulerFn @ main.js:37436
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.js:12385
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ main.js:12334
>   Subscriber._next @ main.js:12287
>   Subscriber.next @ main.js:12251
>   Subject.next @ main.js:14484
>   EventEmitter.emit @ main.js:37428
>   NgZone.triggerError @ main.js:38278
>   onHandleError @ main.js:38257
>   t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   invoke @ polyfills.js:3

> ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:52949
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:110388
>   next @ main.js:35926
>   schedulerFn @ main.js:37436
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.js:12385
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ main.js:12334
>   Subscriber._next @ main.js:12287
>   Subscriber.next @ main.js:12251
>   Subject.next @ main.js:14484
>   EventEmitter.emit @ main.js:37428
>   NgZone.triggerError @ main.js:38278
>   onHandleError @ main.js:38257
>   t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   invoke @ polyfills.js:3

> main.js:52950 Error: No component factory found for AportacionesPage
>       at NoComponentFactoryError.BaseError [as constructor] (main.js:7758)
>       at new NoComponentFactoryError (main.js:24023)
>       at _NullComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (main.js:24032)
>       at AppModuleInjector.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (main.js:24057)
>       at NavControllerBase._viewInit (main.js:29941)
>       at NavControllerBase._nextTrns (main.js:29773)
>       at NavControllerBase._queueTrns (main.js:29744)
>       at NavControllerBase.push (main.js:29588)
>       at ForoHiloPage.irAportaciones (main.js:40843)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ForoHiloPage0.handleEvent_37 (component.ngfactory.js:400)
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:52950
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:110388
>   next @ main.js:35926
>   schedulerFn @ main.js:37436
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.js:12385
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ main.js:12334
>   Subscriber._next @ main.js:12287
>   Subscriber.next @ main.js:12251
>   Subject.next @ main.js:14484
>   EventEmitter.emit @ main.js:37428
>   NgZone.triggerError @ main.js:38278
>   onHandleError @ main.js:38257
>   t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   invoke @ polyfills.js:3

> ERROR CONTEXT:
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:52953
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:110388
>   next @ main.js:35926
>   schedulerFn @ main.js:37436
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.js:12385
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ main.js:12334
>   Subscriber._next @ main.js:12287
>   Subscriber.next @ main.js:12251
>   Subject.next @ main.js:14484
>   EventEmitter.emit @ main.js:37428
>   NgZone.triggerError @ main.js:38278
>   onHandleError @ main.js:38257
>   t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   invoke @ polyfills.js:3

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso solo veo el error de la referencia a la variable `aportaciones` en el método `irAportaciones()`.

[Documentación NavController Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

se debe corregir realizando el ajuste al scope de la clase donde se encuentra de la siguiente manera:

> Es importante usar `this` para acceder a las propiedades de la clase.
>
> Aunque para este caso se puede ahorrar una propiedad adicional y poner directamente la dependencia en `this.navCtrl.push(AportacionesPage)`

```
import { AportacionesPage } from '../aportaciones/aportaciones';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-aportaciones',
  templateUrl: 'aportaciones.html'
})
export class OtraPage {
  private aportaciones = AportacionesPage;

  irAportaciones() {
    console.log('PRUEBA DEL LOG FUNCIONANDO');
    this.navCtrl
      .push(this.aportaciones, {
        //view: 'order'
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log('Response ' + response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
      )
      .catch((exception) => {
        console.log('Exception ' + exception);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo falta declarar el componente dentro del módulo correspondiente: Seguramente tengas un fichero app.module.ts con una anotación del tipo

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    ...
  ]
  ...
```

En el array de `declarations` debes añadir el nuevo componente para que el módulo lo reconozca como suyo:

```
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    ...
    AportacionesPage
  ]
```

Y, además, para poder inyectar el componente, probablemente necesites que esté declarado como un *entry component*:

```
  entryComponents: [ AportacionesPage, ...]
```